# Controlling fields of custom dialog window by javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dialog

I have created a custom dialog and I'm using it in quote entity.
I have 3 fields in it.

Values of fields :

**Field 1 : A**

**Field 2 : B,C**

**Field 3 : D**

Now I just want to display the **Field 3** if user select **"C"** from field 2, otherwise I want to hide field 3.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is Field 2 a <select> tag with options B and C?

Answer (score 0):

Self-solved with using standart dialog conditions.